# Doubt in exercise 8.2 in Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Here is the problem from the book.

> Consider $R^4$ with the standard inner product. Let $W$ be the subspace of $R^4$ consisting of all vectors which are orthogonal to both $\alpha = (1, 0, -1, 1)$ and $\beta = (2, 3, -1, 2)$. Find a basis for $W$.

I am trying to solve this problem using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process but it isn't working out. Is it possible to solve this using Gram-Schmidt process or there is some other way? In either case, please help me as I am reading the book on my own.

Comment: If you are insistent on using Gram-Schmidt, which is not the best approach, please edit and post the work you have done, and then we can give some guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your space as $$W=\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4: \langle(x,y,z,w),(1,0,-1,1)\rangle=0,\,\langle(x,y,z,w),(2,3,-1,2)\rangle=0\}.$$ The two inner product conditions give you a (homogeneous) system of linear equations with two free variables, so you should get a 2-dimensional space.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If you just let a general vector $r=(w,x,y,z)$ be any such vector, then you have 2 equations expressing that $r$ is orthogonal to each of $\alpha,\ \beta$. Work with those equations using say row reduced matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try surely but is it possible using Gram-Schmidt process??

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 What do you want to use the Gram-Schmidt process for? Do you know what its purpose is?

Comment: for getting orthogonal set of vectors from given ones. Although I doubt that can be used in this problem but I wanted to ask because as this is a new topic for me.

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 You don't need an orthogonal basis if all question asks for is a basis.

Comment: they said that basis must be for a subspace that is orthogonal to given set of vectors so I thought of using Gram Schmidt and found two vectors and then I was stuck because the set I got is not orthogonal to both of them

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 What two vectors did you find? If they weren't both orthogonal to each of $\alpha,\ \beta$ then you did something wrrong.

Comment: why should they be orthogonal to both?? If I simply subtracted component of one vector  along other using Gram Schmidt process, it won't become perpendicular to both right?

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 Yes, but your problem says to get a basis for the set of vectors orthogonal to both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so all vectors found, including basis vectors, will be orthogonal to both.

Comment: that's the question I asked. Problem is that Gram Schmidt gives two vectors but they are not perpendicular to both obviously.

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 The basis I got was two vectors $(1,-1/3,1,0),\ (-1,0,0,1).$ A check shows each to be orthogonal to each of $\alpha=(1,0,-1,0)\ \beta=(2,3,-1,2).$ If either of these is altered to make *these* basis vectors also orthogonal to each other, the result will be again two vectors orthogonal to each of $\alpha,\ \beta.$

Comment: I also got this not by Gram Schmidt , but by writing vectors as u mentioned in your answer above and row reducing the matrix. Did u get this vectors by Gram Schmidt process???@coffeemath

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 I got the basis using row reduction as outlined in my answer (not by Gram Schmidt). The rest of my last comment is to the effect that if we did apply Gram Schmidt to that basis it would give two orthogonal vectors which are each orthogonal to alpha and beta.

Comment: Oh . Yes that's true. I was thinking u directly applied Gram Schmidt process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116413/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-nmnsharma-007).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Gram-Schmidt procedure. Extend the set of vectors $\ \{\alpha, \beta\}\ $ to a basis of $\ R^4\ $ by adding another two appropriate vectors to it. The vectors $\ \gamma=(0,0,1,0)\ $ and $\ \delta=(0,0,0,1)\ $ will do for this purpose because $\ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta\ $ are linearly independent.  Now use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to orthonormalise this basis in the order $\ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta\ $.  If the resulting orthonormal basis is $\ u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\ $, then $\ u_1=\frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}\ $ and $\ u_2=\frac{\|\alpha\|^2\beta-\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle\alpha}{\left\| \|\alpha\|^2\beta-\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle\alpha\right\|}\ $ will span the same space as $\ \alpha\ $ and $\ \beta\ $, and $\ u_3, u_4\ $ will be a basis for $\ W\ $.